# How do I create an FCM payload for android and iOS in a Cloud Function

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I am attempting to send a notification using a CLI function to android and iOS devices. The payload I am using is wokring fully on android but not being received on iOS. My current payload looks as follows:

```
const payload = {
  "token": token,
  "notification":{"title": likename + " liked your post!","body": ""},
  "android": {"notification": {"sound": "default"}},
  "apns": {"payload": {"aps": {"sound": "default"}}}
};

return admin.messaging().send(payload).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Comment: Any chance you checked on the client side for iOS if it's being delivered but not displaying the notification?

Comment: I actually just got this solved about an hour ago, I am not sure why but I changed the const to a var and it began to work properly.